# php - using ucfirst for sticking words?

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel

Let's say we want to uppercase the first letter in some strings like :

```
johndev
johnasp
johnphp
johnserver
```

and we use this for such purpose :

```
ucfirst(str_replace($name,ucfirst($name),$result['@attributes']['overflows']))
```

john is our $name variable. It works like this :

```
Johndev //** these also should be in uppercase, for example : JohnDev
Johnasp
Johnphp
Johnserver

DevJohn
AspJohn
PhpJohn
ServerJohn
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I read your question a few times and I must say I don't quite get what you're trying to "fix".

Comment: how do you get the second word ? dev,php,asp ... etc ?

Comment: That depends on your business logic. Do you have a list of possible words? Or a list of possible names?

Given "wonguava" would you expect "WongUava" or "WonGuava" ?

Comment: Ah okay. I think I get what you mean finally.
$name is always the name, while $result['@attributes']['overflows'] is the entire string. Am I getting you correct?

Comment: I don't understand what to fix here. Please explain your question in more details.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
echo 
    ucfirst($name) 
    . ucfirst(substr($result['@attributes']['overflows'], strlen($name)));
```

Here what you do:

- `ucfirst` `$name` itself
- then `ucfirst` part of `$result['@attributes']['overflows']` which comes after `$name`
- concatenate both parts

For strings like 'PhpJohn' just swap parts:

```
echo 
    ucfirst(substr($result['@attributes']['overflows'], strlen($name)))
    . ucfirst($name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `$whole` and `$john`, and `$name` is always the prefix of `$whole`.

```
$whole = "johndev";
$name = "john";
$capName = ucfirst($name); // "John"
$tail = substr($whole, strlen($name)); // "dev"
$capTail = ucfirst($tail); // "Dev"
echo $capName . $capTail; // "JohnDev"
```

If `$name` could appear anywhere in `$whole` for any number of times, then you can use:

```
$whole = "phpjohndevjohnjava";
$name = "john";

$parts = explode($name, $whole); // ["php", "dev", "java"]
$capParts = array_map(ucfirst, $parts); // ["Php", "Dev", "Java"]
$capName = ucfirst($name); // "John"

$answer = implode($capName, $capParts); // "PhpJohnDevJohnJava"
echo $answer;
```

Comment: It's ok , But the problem is that sometimes it returns johndev and sometimes devjohn, So , using `echo $capName . $capTail;` will fail when it returns devjohn

Comment: I see. I've added a more forgiving solution that works for your case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a way to fix this issue :

```
$thekey = str_replace($name, '', $result['@attributes']['overflow']);
$ucname = str_replace($name,ucfirst($name),$result['@attributes']['overflow']);
$thename = str_replace($thekey,ucfirst($thekey),$ucname);
echo ucfirst($thename);
```